# the initial mass m(0) of a population of fish is one thousand tons at the beginning of a year

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

the initial mass m(0) of a population of fish is one thousand tons at the beginning of  a year

the population , if left alone , increases its mass with a proportionality constant 0.1 per month. during august, September and October(only )commercial fishing takes place , removing fish mass at a constant rate of 0.6 thousand of tons per month.

find the mass of the population at the end of September

I'm real confused  . how to start ?

Comment: They may (or may not) mean that left undisturbed, a mass $m_0$ of fish will grow to $m_0(1.1)^t$ in $t$ months. Calculate the mass at the beginning of August, and write down a DE for the behaviour during the fishing period.  Unfortunately, they may mean instead that, undisturbed the mass grows by a factor of $e^{0.1t}$ in $t$ months.